# Windows 10: Screen filled with "e)" upon boot

Tags: windows, windows-10

Well this is a pleasant surprise

[image: Well this is a pleasant surprise]

This is the second time this strange phenomenon has happened.

Surprisingly, a google search does not yield any results. A simple force restart solved it

So what is this and how can I fix it

Comment: This might be a hardware problem. Did you try to reinstall windows?

Comment: maybe uninstall Edge ;)

Comment: When, exactly, does this screen appear?